# change databound listbox to longlistselector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I have a Listbox which items can be open & view by following code...

```
    private void AccountsList_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
            var listBoxItem = AccountsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AccountsList.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
            var txtBlk = FindVisualChildByType<TextBlock>(listBoxItem, "txtBlkAccountName");
            xCa = txtBlk.Text;

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/ViewAccount.xaml?parameter={0}&action={1}", a.ToString(), "View"), UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

&

```
    T FindVisualChildByType<T>(DependencyObject element, String name) where T : class
    {
        if (element is T && (element as FrameworkElement).Name == name)
        {
            return element as T;
        }

        int childcount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);

        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++)
        {
            T childElement = FindVisualChildByType<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i), name);
            if (childElement != null)
            {
                return childElement;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

now i am implementing longlistselector instead of the listbox.
Long List Selector shows all my items from database but i am having problem while opening an item from this list... i cant use SelectedIndex in this longlistselector PLEASE HELP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change your workflow. Instead of listening to the Tap event, listen to the SelectionChanged event. From this event you can get the SelectedItem. The SelectItem is the object the Items are bound to.

Example: Your ItemsSource is List each item within the ListBox or LongListSelector is bound to an instance of MyObject. Your "txtBlkAccountName" TextBlock should have it's Text bound to the AccountNumber property of your MyObject class.

```
private void LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myObj = AccountsList.SelectedItem as MyObject;
    if(myObj == null) return;

    var accountNum = myObj.AccountNumber;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/ViewAccount.xaml?parameter={0}&action={1}", accountNum, "View"), UriKind.Relative));

    // set the selectedItem to null so the page can be navigated to again 
    // If the user taps the same item
    AccountsList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the item tapped, place the Tap even inside the ItemTemplate not the List, then you can use the sender property  to retrieve the value you want.
Also instead of using FindVisualChildByType to get the value you want you should be able to just use the DataContext to retrieve whatever you want:

```
private void AccountsItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
        FrameworkElement element=sender as FrameworkElement ;
        Account item= element.DataContext as Account ;

        xCa = item.Name;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/ViewAccount.xaml?parameter={0}&action={1}", a.ToString(), "View"), UriKind.Relative));
}
```